# Yeoman HTML Wiring Examples

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I've seen various posts that suggest Yeoman's wiring is going to be handled by the [HTML Wiring](https://github.com/yeoman/html-wiring) package and that the methods in Yeoman itself are now deprecated.

There are no docs at all on the Wiring. Does anyone have any idea how it works or examples of it's use that I can crib from?

Thanks